# Count strings occurrences and plot histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, cell

Is there any straightforward way to create a histogram from a cell array like the one below? The spacing between the consecutive bars should be exactly the same and the labels of the x-axis should be the corresponding names of the variables below in a vertical orientation.

```
'w464'
'w462'
'w461'
'w464'
'w461'
'w463'
'w466'
'w461'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to know a better way, as well.  Fwiw, I have used [countmember](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7738) in a roundabout way to plot data like this.  I.E. if the data you posted was named `A`

```
>> B={sort(unique(A)) countmember(sort(unique(A)),A)};
>> bar(B{2});
>> set(gca,'XTickLabel',B{1})
```

Comment: Oh, to change the orientation of your labels, check out [Rotate X-axis tick labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) from the file exchange.

Comment: Thank you again! You are my hero! :D

Comment: @AGS: there is a slightly more simple way using `grp2idx`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to the statistics toolbox, `grp2idx` is very useful:

```
%# sorting is only necessary if the output should be sorted as well
[idx,label] = grp2idx(sort(A)) 

hist(idx,unique(idx));
set(gca,'xTickLabel',label)
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution that only uses built-in functions

```
[u,~,n] = unique(A(:));
B = accumarray(n, 1, [], @sum);
bar(B)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',u)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the histogram function as follows:

```
[C,~,ic] = unique(A);

fig1 = figure;
axes1 = axes('Parent',fig1,'XTickLabel',C,'XTick',1:length(C));
hold(axes1,'on');

histogram(ic)
```