# How can I determine the relative frequency of a string value in a MATLAB vector?

Tags: matlab

How can I determine the relative frequency of a string value in a MATLAB vector?

```
vector = { 'aa', 'f', 'aa', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k' };
```

What function will return the number of occurrences of each unique element?

Comment: You probably mean `vector = { 'aa', 'f', 'aa', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k' };`

Comment: tabulate(vector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967154/count-strings-occurences-and-plot-histogram) which needs a file from FEX. You can use builtin functions in MATLAB for that. Say,

```
vector = { 'aa', 'f', 'aa', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k' };
```

One can use

```
[u,~,n] = unique(vector(:));
B = accumarray(n, 1, [], @sum);
bar(B)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',u)
```

which produces

[image]

**EDIT:** Borrowing from [Eitan T's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408463/how-can-i-determine-the-relative-frequency-of-a-string-value-in-a-matlab-vector#comment25279717_17408891) one can use `histc` instead of `accumarray`, i.e.

```
B = histc(n,1:max(n));
```

Comment: +1: I didn't notice that neither question suggested a native solution. You'd probably be better using `histc` instead of `accumarray`, it's more intuitive.

Comment: @EitanT good point, though I add that to the answer.

Comment: What the `~` in `[u,~,n] = unique(vector(:));` stands for ???

Comment: It means that we are not interested in second output argument, so it is not assigned to any variable. It's needed because we want to access the third output argument.

Comment: your answer is not clear for me! would you mind explain more? I review that answer you mentioned, but because I use version 7 of matlab there isn't command 'countmember'! do you know any command I used instead of it?